# In the official Sentinel 1 GRD product in SAFE format, where is the view/incidence angle?

Tags: sentinel-1, sentinel-snap, sar

As the title says, I am trying to figure out where in the metadata is the information on view angle stored. I can see it has information on min and max view angle, but I want a raster with the angle of incidence for each pixel (or a spatially subset version of that).

1. Is that available somewhere in the metadata?
2. Or if it's not, is there some way of calculating it, not relying in e.g. SNAP?